# Is it possible to set a default value for a twitter image through TCAdefaults in Page TSconfig typo3

Tags: typo3, typoscript, tsconfig

[image: this twitter image]

I know I can do it for the title and description but is it also possible with the image there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to work with a `TCA default` value here, since the actual field does not contain the information about the related image, but just the number of attached relations. Anything else is provided by the `sys_file_reference` table, which is used to handle the relation to the images.

So to solve your problem you should work with a default image in the `Fluid Templates` for your pages, that will always be used, if there is no related image available.